# Can I detect if IIS will dynamically compress content from within filter code?

Tags: asp.net, iis, orchardcms

I have implemented `IActionFilter` to minify HTML output of a page. I'd like to display some statistics about this process, but relevant numbers differ depending on whether page will be in the end served uncompressed or gzipped.

Problem I'm facing is that filter works on uncompressed response which lacks any headers or indication that client will be getting page gzipped, that is probably happening further down the pipe by IIS. Can I somehow check if IIS is intending to send page gzipped?